# Force media to be mounted to /dev/sr1 instead of /dev/sr0

Tags: linux, mount

I would like to be able to have the first device that I mount to a linux host be `/dev/sr1` instead of `/dev/sr0`.

I am trying to script installing IBM’s SVC. There installer is hardcoded to expect the boot the cd and search `/dev/sr1` for files. Another limitation is that their RDCLI which allows virtual media mounting can only mount a single ISO.

So when I mount the ISO `.\rdmount.exe -s IMM IP address -d path/to/svc-install.iso -l Username -p Password`

I successfully mount the ISO to `sr0` and can’t run the installer.

If rdmount allowed me to mount multiple ISO’s I could just mount the `install.iso` twice.

I haven’t been able to find a method to change `sr0` to `sr1` once it is mounted or to have it mount directly to `sr0`. Symlinks and udev haven't helped because those only help once the OS is loaded.

If I make folder `/dev/sr0` and mount something to it. Then try to run the rdmount command it appears to not mount.

> newinstall:/dev/disk/by-id # ls scsi-3600605b0045637c019eaca5719c9d3a9 scsi-3600605b0045637c019eaca5719c9d3a9-part1 scsi-3600605b0045637c019eaca5719c9d3a9-part10 scsi-3600605b0045637c019eaca5719c9d3a9-part11 scsi-3600605b0045637c019eaca5719c9d3a9-part12 scsi-3600605b0045637c019eaca5719c9d3a9-part13 scsi-3600605b0045637c019eaca5719c9d3a9-part2 scsi-3600605b0045637c019eaca5719c9d3a9-part4 scsi-3600605b0045637c019eaca5719c9d3a9-part5 scsi-3600605b0045637c019eaca5719c9d3a9-part6 scsi-3600605b0045637c019eaca5719c9d3a9-part7 scsi-3600605b0045637c019eaca5719c9d3a9-part8 scsi-3600605b0045637c019eaca5719c9d3a9-part9

When I unmount this ISO and run the `rdmount` command it looks to have mounted but `sr0` remains a directory unless I delete it first.

> newinstall:/dev/disk/by-id # ls -ltar |grep sr lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Aug 28 18:05 usb-IBM_IBM_Composite_Device-0_20070221-15 -> ../../sr0 newinstall:/dev/disk/by-id # file /dev/sr0 /dev/sr0: directory newinstall:/dev/disk/by-id # ls -ltar /dev/sr0 total 0 drw-rw---- 2 root disk 40 Aug 28 17:58 . drwxrwxrwt 13 root root 4100 Aug 28 18:05 ..

Does anyone have an explanation for this last mount pointing to an empty folder? Are the symlinks created even if the mount catastrophically fails?

Answer (score 0):

I would still be interested if anyone can elaborate on what happened, but if you have the same problem I would suggest you create a usb.img and mount that. Otherwise you have to catch the SVC installer before kernel and change `sr0` to `sr1`. There is a 10 second window on changing that setting.

They wrote this installer when all their machines had CD drives so they assumed `sr0` would always be occupied and any mounted iso would be on `sr1`. A reminder to all of us to abstract your software from your hardware, because we can't predict how things will change.